# Solving recurrence relation varying with parity of n

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a sequence $u_n$ such that

$u_1 = 1$

$u_{2n} = n + u_n$

$u_{2n+1} = n^2 + u_nu_{n+1}$

How to solve for closed-form of $u_n$? I really don't know where to start.

Comment: One simple way to start is to tabulate $u_n$ for small values of $n$; I did it for $n=1,\ldots,16$ and got $$1,2,3,4,10,6,21,8,56,15,85,12,162,28,217,16\;,$$ which is not very promising as far as a closed form is concerned. And it’s more than enough to discover that [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) has no entry for the sequence. (It is clear, though, that $u_{2^n}=2^n$ for all $n$, for whatever that may be worth.)

Comment: And somewhat more generally, $u_{2^m k} = (2^m - 1) k + u(k)$ for odd $k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think there is a closed form?  It's unlikely for an arbitrary nonlinear recurrence. Neither [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%2C%2010%2C%206%2C%2021%2C%208%2C%2056%2C%2015%2C%2085%2C%2012%2C%20162%2C%2028%2C%20217%2C%2016%2C%20512&sort=&language=&go=Search) nor [gfun](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/bruno.salvy/software/the-gfun-package/) come up with anything.